# Delete **Contents:** in index of pdf generated with python-spihnx

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, pdflatex

I have a project created with `python-sphinx` and I use `latexpdf` to compile the final pdf.

In the final pdf created, in the *index* it is visible a *Contents:* string that I would like to delete.

[image]

The only way I found by now is to compile only the `latex`, open the `.tex` file, look for the string and delete that from there.

Then compile the pdf via latex `make all-pdf`.

Is there a way to specify that?

Comment: This is pythyn/sphinx related, so I think it's OK to have this question here at SO, but possible see also if the texperts at tex.stackexchange can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you have `**Contents**` as part of the normal .rst markup and use it as a header before the table of contents (ToC), which is fine in your html.

For LaTeX, however, one ToC is assembled (if there are multiple) and used as the one and only ToC at the beginning of the document. ToCs are not displayed inline. That's why your ToC is displayed **before** your `**Contents**` markup.

To **just fix** this issue you *can* use Spinx's [.. only:: directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/misc.html?highlight=only#including-content-based-on-tags):

```
.. only:: html

     **Contents**
```

Alternatively **and to do things the proper way**, you can use the `:caption:` option of the [toctree directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html):

```
.. toctree::
   :caption: Contents

   your-content
   here
```